# How to correctly mix JTA and JPA transaction in Spring application

Tags: spring-data-jpa, distributed-transactions

My Spring application was using JPA transaction manager but for some situations I would like to use JTA transaction manager. Therefore I updated Spring config to something like that:

```
<beans>
  <!-- Old config -->
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <!-- ...-->
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>

  <!-- ...-->

  <!-- Updated config-->
  <util:map id="jpaPropertyMap" key-type="java.lang.String">
    <!-- ... ->
    <entry key="javax.persistence.transactionType" value="jta"/>
    <entry key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="Atomikos"/>
  </util:map>

  <bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="forceShutdown" value="false"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp"/>

  <bean id="jtaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- ...-->

</beans>
```

Now in Java code when I need several JPA transactions (to different databases) to act as one transaction I annotate the starting service method with `@Transactional("jtaTransactionManager")`, while for situation when I need a single transaction I use standard `@Transactional` annotation.

But I have observed that, because of the properties

```
<entry key="javax.persistence.transactionType" value="jta"/>
<entry key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="Atomikos"/>
```

even if I start a sigle JPA transaction, Hibernate internally is also using Atomikos transaction manager. Is it possible to have Hibernate use Atomikos for JTA transaction and to not use it for single JPA transactions?